# How to implement generic method in C# having multiple constraints

Tags: c#, generics

I want to write a generic method:

```
void Foo<T>(IList<T> list)
```

In the method, I want to compare elements of list either by using operator < if T is primitive type or Compare() if T implements IComparable.

Is this possible? If not, it means C# generics is very limited in use I think.

Comment: What I mean is: in C++, it is up to compiler to check if a call is valid at instantiation. But C# has stronger requirement and hence narrow use of generics.

Comment: You say "narrow" I say "absolutely fine in the vast majority of cases where I've wanted to use generics."

Comment: @Jon Skeet, really "absolutely fine", even when you need so tricky way to call operator+ in a generic method? (Yes, I read your other article just now). IMO, C# at least needs some contract specification for generics that say "T requires to have operator+ overloaded" or "T requires to have method of such signature".

Comment: It's absolutely fine in the vast majority of cases where I've wanted to use generics, because in that vast majority of cases I haven't wanted to call operator+ - it's as simple as that. You say that C# "needs" some contract specification - you might *like* it (and so might I) but that's not the same as "needing" it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is this possible? If not, it means C# generics is very limited in use I think.

Even if it *weren't* possible, generics can be used in many *many* situations.

However, it's really simple given that all the primitive types implement `IComparable<T>`;

```
void Foo<T>(IList<T> list) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T x = ...;
    T y = ...;
    if (x.CompareTo(y) < 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that this will *not* introduce boxing operations. I'd expect the JITted code for primitive types to end up having *very* similar performance to hardcoding it to use `<` or `>`.

Now this is a slightly special case, because there's an interface which is roughly equivalent to those operators. What *isn't* as easy is using arithmetic operators (`+`, `-` etc). See the [article on my web site](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html) for a few approaches to this.

Comment: Thanks, @Jon Skeet You answered to my question and also confirmed that C# generics is not as flexible and powerful as C++ template.

Comment: @Sheen: They're not the same, and weren't *meant* to be the same. There are benefits of each approach, and each is suitable for the design of the language it's part of.